# Pydantic and PurePosixPath from pathlib

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a settings class built with [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) with a `Path` field. I need this path as Unix Path, because it is to navigate in a Data Lake

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):

    DATALAKE_MODEL_RESULT_PATH: Path
```

The problem with class above is that if I'm on windows for example, the path is treated as a windows path even if in the dotenv file was written as Unix (that does the `Path` class).

So I tried

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):

    DATALAKE_MODEL_RESULT_PATH: PurePosixPath
```

but pydantic doesn't recognize it

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Settings
DATALAKE_MODEL_RESULT_PATH
  instance of PurePosixPath expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=PurePosixPath)
```

Maybe I need a Custom Field? validator?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validator which will coerce a path into the proper format:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pydantic import validator

class Settings(BaseSettings):

    DATALAKE_MODEL_RESULT_PATH: Path

   @validator('DATALAKE_MODEL_RESULT_PATH')
   def validate_path(cls, v):
      return Path(v)
```

This should resolve path configs between windows and linux, but I'm not 100% sure. However, additional validation can take place within the validator function -> so if you choose to augment this solution, put your further work there.